# Improving blocking user from downloading video

Tags: .htaccess, video-streaming, html5-video

I need some advice in blocking user to download video from my site. 
**I knw it is impossible to do it fully but**

still things i have done -

Rename Htaccess of /video.mp4 to /video

*(Because i have renamed video name like random numbers so it takes little time to actually find it.)*

Blocking Htaccess of all my MP4

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Anymore tips guys which i can improve ??

**Imp. Question- Does blocking Htaccess really help blocking url directly even for computer genius/crackers too ?**

Info-  I am using MediaElement.js simple basic html5 code player

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I will be honest, if the client has to view it, there probably is no way to stop it. The only thing you could possibly do is use a completely custom player that accepts encrypted traffic.

Comment: How can i do that where to start with ?? and i have forbidden the permission to direct download thomas please till me still any process any one can still directly download ???

Comment: I don't get encrypted traffic ??

Comment: If your client's browser needs to download it, then there is always away to download it by other means. Unless you had a custom movie player  that uses an encrypted file, then it decrypted it then played...you really can't prevent the download.

Comment: Thomas even if i have blocked the direct link ?? still ?? i have custom movie player but can i encrypt mp4 files ??

Comment: first you said encrypted traffic now you're saying encrypted file ?? Sorry but I'm not getting your words..correctly i think

Comment: Traffic is the file, everything the user's client gets is traffic. I'll put it this way, you're putting time into something not fightable, since anyone who wants to can easily get it.